# AWS SES - Stat=Sent

Tags: monitoring, amazon-ses

My organization sends 60k of email a week on SES. I track bounces and complaints in CloudWatch and with an SNS topic. Every now and again I need to confirm delivery of a specific email. I used to grep for stat=sent in the mail log. I never thought I'd miss those days but setting up an SNS topic and subscribing to it just to get the log is a real cringe, don't you think? That's just a lot of unnecessary traffic. Is there a simple, better way?